# Find and replace with wildcards

Tags: excel, replace

I want to change the formulas in a 200x200 table by using find and replace.

My old formula is `='Sheet1'!A1*IF(B4=C2,1,0)` and I want to replace it with `=('Sheet1'!A1-'Sheet1'!B1)*IF(B4=C2,1,0)`

Since doing it a cell at a time is tedious, I tried to use find and replace, but I could not keep the referenced cells. Is there a way to do it?

This is how the first cells of my data look like
[image]

I cannot fill down or right, since  if I fill down I want to keep the reference to C2 while changing the reference to B4 (something like `B4-$C$2`), while if I fill right I want to keep the reference to B4 and change the reference to C2 (something like `$B$4-C2`)

Comment: What happens if you "fill down" or "fill right"?

Comment: that's the problem: if I do that the references get messed up. if I fill down I want to keep the reference to C2, while if I fill right I want to keep the reference to B4

Comment: How does it get messed up? You have only given us one example. It's impossible for us to understand the logic from one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have a bit of a workaround, I'd use it for one cell, and then mess about with the IF references depending on your needs for expanding down and right, as without seeing your dataset it's hard to envisage exactly how you want it, I hope this gives you the right idea, but may need a bit of messing about with.

Firstly, you want to get the cell with your original forumula in (let's say it's in A1). In an empty cell (let's say B1), you want to put =FORMULATEXT(A1). Then in another empty cell (let's say C1), you want to put:

```
="=(" & MID(B1,2,10) & "-Sheet1!B1" & ")" & MID(B1,11,20)
```

One thing to also maybe note is that my Excel doesn't produce quotes around the Sheet names, so you may need to mess about with the MID numbers (so probably change the 10 in the first mid to a 12, I think?) I've put the final MID number as 20 just to account for longer formulas.

Copy the cell. Now go to a new worksheet and in A1, you want to right click and paste values. Now, this part is important, you want to click into the formula bar and then press enter. This should now give the formula:

```
=(Sheet1!A1*-Sheet1!B1)*IF(B4=C2,1,0)
```

Now you can go into the formula bar, copy this and paste it back into your original sheet. Like I said, you should then mess about with the $ for the IF statement depending on your needs for expanding the data. Sorry it's a bit of a long workaround, but it's all I can find to do!